# Make the width of the input changed due to the window resize with the dynamic label width before it

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have a problem with the positioning input element inside the holder container.

The html structure is:

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center">
    <form>
        <div class="input-holder">
            <span>
                Label
            </span>
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

The `center` div has the next css rules:

```
position: absolute;
right: 200px;
left: 200px;
width: 100%;
```

So it always displays in the `center` of the screen, and change it width when window resizing.

**The problem:**

I want to make input inside `center` container has the width 100%, and with the dynamically changed lable width and window resizing, input change it's width accordingly, so I will have smth like this:
http://3.1m.yt/zBBsvn-.png

Answer (score -1):

.input-holder{
margin:0 auto
}